# Functional programming Totallylazy tutorial

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

I want to learn the functional programming way provided by Totallylazy library.

However, I can't find any good tutorial or books on the web. Even on the official site, seems the document is less than the Guava.

Even on stackoverflow, there is no tags for totallylazy.

Any recommendation for that? Or who can create a tag for that?

Comment: I am not sure just why you want to do this, but note that many of the functional java libraries are going to become obsoleted with Java 8. As an alternative, I recommend to learn a real lazy programming language, if it is lazyness you're looking for.

Comment: fyi, this is not a library by Google, it's hosted on Google Code